# get Selected Value in JavaScript from ztree

Tags: javascript, ztree

I have a tree which i took sample form zTree but i am unable to get the selected value from this tree. although i have made changes to the original code but here i am posting the original code of official Ztree Demo. Any help!!

```
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
    var setting = {
        data: {
            simpleData: {
                enable: true
            }
        }
    };
```

Array to Store the Nodes of Tree

```
    var zNodes =[
        { id:1, pId:0, name:"pNode 1", open:true},
        { id:11, pId:1, name:"pNode 11"},
        { id:111, pId:11, name:"leaf node 111"},
        { id:12, pId:1, name:"pNode 12"},
        { id:121, pId:12, name:"leaf node 121"},
        { id:13, pId:1, name:"pNode 13 - no child", isParent:true},
        { id:2, pId:0, name:"pNode 2"},
        { id:21, pId:2, name:"pNode 21", open:true},
        { id:211, pId:21, name:"leaf node 211"},
        { id:22, pId:2, name:"pNode 22"},
        { id:221, pId:22, name:"leaf node 221"},
        { id:23, pId:2, name:"pNode 23"},
        { id:231, pId:23, name:"leaf node 231"},
        { id:3, pId:0, name:"pNode 3 - no child", isParent:true}
    ];
```

Tree initialization from that array

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.fn.zTree.init($("#treeDemo"), setting, zNodes);
    });
</SCRIPT>
```

Here Tree Displays in Div with id treeDemo. Here i want to alert the selected value in alert box from this tree.

```
<BODY>
     <div class="content_wrap">
          <div class="zTreeDemoBackground left">
               <ul id="treeDemo" class="ztree"></ul>
          </div>
     </div>
</BODY>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On zTree v3.x, 
You need two things:

1) In settings, add a callback

```
var setting = {
        ...
        callback: {
            onCheck: zTreeOnCheck
        }
    };
```

2) ztreeOnCheck in the callback, you get with each check/unchek all selected nodes. Sample

```
function zTreeOnCheck(event, treeId, treeNode) {
  var treeObj = $.fn.zTree.getZTreeObj("treeDemo");
  var nodes = treeObj.getCheckedNodes(true);
  console.log(nodes); //Here are all of the selected nodes
};
```

Comment: "onClick" instead of onCheck worked for me, parameters being same.

Answer (score 0):

Get the JSON data objects collection of the selected nodes in zTree.
Please use zTree object to executing the method.

`var treeObj = $.fn.zTree.init($("#treeDemo"), setting, zNodes);
var nodes = treeObj.getSelectedNodes();`

Then from "nodes" you can get necessary data.

Comment: This answer would be better if it would explain the code.

Comment: although i found alternative to this but if you can explain this in more detailed way I'll prefer this to use in my application. Thanks!

Comment: @ammarali29 i did some changes.